# Installing driver works through batchfile but not using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, drivers

I have installed a driver named Abc.inf using a batchfile which contains
RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 %~dp0ABC.inf.

When I run the batchfile, the driver installs successfully and I can view it using driverquery command in cmd.

Now I try the same using c++. My code being

```
LPWSTR cmdLine = L"DefaultInstall 132 C:\\ABC.inf";

InstallHinfSection(NULL,NULL,cmdLine,0);
```

A small popup comes and vanishes incredibly fast(so fast that I'm not able to read what it is). The function executes successfully but there is no such entries of the driver when I check using command prompt.

Am I missing out anything in this? Any solutions?

Comment: 32 bit vs. 64 bit issue, most likely. We cannot help you with that, as there is no information regarding that in your question.

Comment: Is your program running elevated?  I would think this is necessary to install a driver.

Comment: It is not either as the driver works fine when we run through a batch file Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958760/install-update-driver-from-windows-service , the person had the same problem where he couldnt install a driver using windows service. 


And the program is running under administrative privileges. I even checked the logs. It doesnt show any error message.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958760/install-update-driver-from-windows-service